# My computer keeps restarting when I try to install Ubuntu. Why?

Tags: 12.04, installation, 13.10

I've tried both 13.10 and 12.04 LTS but neither work. I can get it to boot from my USB, and I go through the process like normal up until the point where I select "Install inside Windows 7" and click continue, then it restarts my system. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the steps:

1. Before booting the installation disc try to make sure the you have an empty partition with some space greater than 10GB. Note the label(name) of the parition.
2. Restart and follow the instruction just as you previously did.
3. Try to install it with the option 'Something else' and select the empty partition that you've created.
4. Click Change below and select the file format as 'Ext4' and check 'Format the partition' and select the mount point as '/'.
5. Then follow the installation with your desired steps...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are going into the live cd and using an option to install from within windows 7, I have never seen that option inside the livecd, but if you found it it would make sense that it would restart so you can go inside windows 7 and install as you wish. I would suggest that when you go into the livecd, to choose the option to install without trying it out, so that it goes directly into the installer.

If you are inside windows 7 that is something i am familiar with, when i tried double clicking the installer it would tell me that it was going to restart so i could go into the livecd.

I have never tried to install actually from within windows 7, i choose to restart, but in that case Wubi seems to be the right path.

Decide if you want to install from within windows 7 or through the live cd, and then proceed to download the appropiate installer X_x